# .gitignore exclusion when a folder name is unknown

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my folder structure (in `find *` Unix format)

```
Project
Project/hi.txt
Project/userdata
Project/userdata/username
Project/userdata/username/info.txt
Project/userdata/username/cool
Project/userdata/username/cool/foo.txt
Project/userdata/username/cool/bar.txt
```

How can I use `.gitignore` to exclude everything in the `userdata` folder **except** for the `cool` folder? This solution should **not rely** on what `username` actually is.

Comment: Will the `cool` folder be only inside two directory levels below `userdata` or it can be anywhere inside `userdata` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` supports inclusions too, not just exclusions. An inclusion negates an exclusion. The caveat is if you exclude a folder, it never even tests the inclusions against the folder's contents. So you'll want to set up your .gitignore to look like (and I'm assuming it's inside `Project/` already)

```
/userdata/*
!/userdata/*/
/userdata/*/*
!/userdata/*/cool/
```

This says "ignore everything in `/userdata`, but don't ignore folders, but do ignore everything inside nested folders, but don't ignore a doubly-nested folder named `cool`".

Comment: But what if we're not already inside `Project/`? Suppose everything is in yet another superfolder `superfolder` and the `.gitignore` is within that superfolder. In this case, simply removing the slashes at the beginning of your ignore rules does **not** work. Any ideas why not?

Comment: By experimenting I found that in this case that I had to add `*/` before each rule (or right after the `!` of course). Then it would work. But it would **not** work if I started right away with `userdata/*`, `!userdata/*/`, etc. Can you explain why?

Comment: @steve882: The presence of a `/` in the ignore pattern anchors the pattern to the current folder. As a matter of habit I always prefix patterns with a `/` to anchor them, even if they contain a `/` already, so I don't have to think about it.